# Отключение логов org.eclipse.jgit

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository

Как отключить логи у JGIT org.eclipse.jgit? Пробовал через logback, но отключаются и логи spring. Не нагуглил решение. ineedhelp

```
10:59:20.402 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\Users\user\.gitconfig, is unmodified
10:59:20.403 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\repositories\Student1\Task1.git\config, isRacyClean=false, read=2021-03-16 10:59:20.353609500, lastModified=2021-01-26 13:17:51.567028000, delta=4225288786581500 ns, racy<=2500000000 ns
10:59:20.403 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\repositories\Student1\Task1.git\config, is unmodified
10:59:20.411 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\repositories\Student1\Task1.git\objects\pack, isRacyClean=false, read=2021-03-16 10:59:20.374665700, lastModified=2021-02-02 15:54:16.029114000, delta=3611104345551700 ns, racy<=7325000 ns
10:59:20.411 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\repositories\Student1\Task1.git\objects\pack, is unmodified
```

Comment: в `properties` попробуйте добавить `logging.level.org.eclipse.jgit=ERROR`

Comment: не работает такое. пробовал